# impact of incorrect message size in old unix message queues routines

Tags: c, linux, unix, message-queue, mq

I'm reverse engineering a program that uses Unix Message queues (the old ones, not Posix) and I saw that the size provided to msgsnd or msgrcv is not correct, it is bigger than what it should be. Example :

```
struct requestmir  {
   long type;
   char name[128];
   int timeout;
   long test;
};
int sizereqmir=sizeof(struct requestmir);
```

"sizereqmir" is used in msgsnd but according to some websites, the size of "type" (sizeof(long)) must be substracted from "sizereqmir".

If we use a bigger size (without substracting the size of the type), can a buffer overflow occur (with no consequences) ? because the program is running properly but I need to know if I have to correct the sizes.

And for msgrcv, does the size indicate the maximum size to read ? if 2 small messages are sent to a message queue and I want to read only one message but I provide a big size, will I found the 2 messages in my buffer whereas I want only one message ? Example :

```
// in processes that send msg logs...
// shared struct
struct log{
   long type;
   char text[512];
};

struct log mess;
mess.type= 15;
//... put some text in log.text
if(msgsnd(msgqId,&mess,strlen(mess.text)+1, IPC_NOWAIT);
//....
// EOF #####

//*** in the process that read log msg from the message queue and write them to a file

struct log mess;
msgrcv(msgqId,&mess,512,0,0); //512 max text size
```

In the last msgrcv, I try to read 512 bytes max from the queue, if 2 different processes send short log messages, they will be found in "mess", it that correct ?

Comment: _the program is running properly but I need to know if I have to correct the sizes._... If the program is running correctly, then it seems like you are asking for ideas on optimization, or a code review.  If that is the case, you might get better results for this kind of question _[the stack exchange code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)_.  (and please check your spelling, and punctuation.  It is difficult to follow what you are asking)

Comment: @ryyker If _the program is running properly_ it is still possible that he has tons of undefined behaviour and just doesn't face any crasehs or other obvious faults while it is just by accident not formatting his hard drive.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: @rykker But the question is exactly this, is the code running correctly (as in not potentially formatting his hard drive). That makes it off-topic on Code Review (and it will soon be closed there as off-topic because of this). For reference, the question is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167250/impact-of-incorrect-message-size-in-old-unix-message-queues-routines).

Comment: @Aminos - You are welcome.  Although I appreciate the sentiment, and support shown by the other comments, I still suggest the best direction for this type of question, as it is now, would be the StackExchange Code review site as I linked in my previous comment, or maybe the algorithms site.  However, If this post was edited to conform to the the _[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_ for this site, I am pretty sure you  would see more positive activity here.  It already has the beginnings of a good question.  Consider editing.